# Expanded and Flexible work not fine toghter in one Row

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

**You Can look this demo in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/22faf6ac3b9ebcf92163af7bb42ea162)**

**Pseudo Code:**

```
 Column(
              children: [
                Row(children: [
                  fleWid(1),
                  expWid(1),
                ]),
                Row(children: [
                  expWid(1),
                  expWid(1),
                ]),
                Row(children: [
                  fleWid(1),
                  fleWid(1),
                ]),
```

**Screen:**
[image]

**Repeat**：**You Can look this demo in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/22faf6ac3b9ebcf92163af7bb42ea162)**

**The problemm is the *Row1*,why *Expanded* cannot expand the full rest space ?**

Comment: If you want for expanded to fill the remaining widget, use the another one without flexible. Why do you want to use flexible and expanded together, what is the output that you desire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the expanded and the flexible have a flex of 1 so they both get to layout in 1 / (1+1) so half the width.

However, the flexible has a flexfit that allows it to be smaller than the maximum of half the width.

If you want the expanded to use the full width you should remove the flexible around the smaller part

Answer (score 1):

Expanded will take the whole available space, while Flexible only take needed space.
In your case, inside Flexible is a Text widget with a default fontSize of 14, so Flexible, will only wrap around Text.

> Using a Flexible widget gives a child of a Row, Column, or Flex the flexibility to expand to fill the available space in the main axis (e.g., horizontally for a Row or vertically for a Column), but, unlike Expanded, Flexible does not require the child to fill the available space.

You can check the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html)